# I have a Desktop Application, and I want to turn it into a mobile application with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

So my company already has a long running application they've been using and updating for decades. But it's only ever been used and programmed for a desktop. It's all coded in Visual Studios in C#, which is what I understood is what's needed to use Xamarin. So they want to turn it into a mobile application now.

I was curious can I turn this Desktop application into Mobile Application through Xamarin? Does it change the C# written in Visual studios into something usable for iOS? Or did the C# already have to be set up to be used for a mobile application? Which confused me because I don't know of any phones that are programmed in C#.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introduction_to_mobile_development/

Comment: It will have to be re-written for a mobile application. Xamarin is in C#, but the logic and use of the SDKs are very specific to mobile. You may be able to reuse some of the business logic, but it wont be a simple port.

Comment: Okay, thanks that's what I was afraid of. So is there a basis to programming a mobile app off C#? I thought all mobile apps where programmed in Objective-C or Java

Comment: And so you think it's something I would probably have to start from scratch then to make it workable for a mobile application. Or could I keep the same basic framework?Sorry if these are bad questions, I'm more new to coding and they kind of just threw me into the deep end on this at work.